# Removing trailing zeros from number if it is an integer

Tags: javascript

So I am learning javascript, and I have not been working with it for very long, and I have the following code:

```js
function doslope() {
  var b, m;
  x1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x1").value);
  y1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y1").value);
  x2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x2").value);
  y2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y2").value);
  m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
  b = y1 - m * x1;
  m = m.toFixed(2);
  b = b.toFixed(2);

  if (Number.isInteger(m)) {
    m = parseInt(m.toString());
  }

  if (Number.isInteger(b)) {
    b = parseInt(b.toString());
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "y=" + m + "x+" + b;
}
```

```html
<label>x1<input id="x1" /></label><br>
<label>y1<input id="y1" /></label><br>
<label>x2<input id="x2" /></label><br>
<label>y2<input id="y2" /></label><br>
<button onclick="doslope()">Do slope</button><br>
<br>
<output id="result"></output>
```

When I run this with the numbers `x1=5`, `y1=5`, `x2=6`, and `y2=3` I get the result `y=-2.00x+15.00`.

I am wondering what error I am making here that it is not removing the `.00` at the end of the number.

Comment: A string is not an integer, hence the values are never parsed to numbers.

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` is what outputs `'.00'`

Comment: As of your `if (Number.isInteger(m)) {` check, `m` is a **string**, not a number, and `Number.isInteger` doesn't do any implicit conversion of values. All strings are not integers according to that function. Instead, check as you're converting to string (rather than after): `m = Number.isInteger(m) ? String(m) : m.toFixed(2);` Separately, remember to declare all your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Number.isInteger()` checks the type of the value and since your `m` and `b` variables are string it will always return false.
What you could do is temporarily convert them into float:

```
  if (Number.isInteger(parseFloat(m))) {
    m = parseInt(m.toString());
  }
```

Alternatively (and in your case I think would be a better option) is to simply remove `.00` from the string itself:

```
  m = m.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
  b = b.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `if` statements you have, are returning you false, so you are not making the parseInt, if you take them out, it works correctly:

```
    function doslope() {
            var b, m;
            x1 = parseFloat(5);
            y1 = parseFloat(5);
            x2 = parseFloat(6);
            y2 = parseFloat(3);
            m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
            b = y1 - m * x1;
            m = m.toFixed(2);
            b = b.toFixed(2);

            m = parseInt(m.toString());

            b = parseInt(b.toString());

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "y=" + m + "x+" + b;
    }
```

Why are you using that if statement?

If you want that the user can only put numbers, you can try with something like this: `type="number"` just allows to put numbers, and `step="0.01"` allows you to put decimal numbers

```
<label>x1<input id="x1" type="number" step="0.01" /></label><br>
<label>y1<input id="y1" type="number" step="0.01" /></label><br>
<label>x2<input id="x2" type="number" step="0.01" /></label><br>
<label>y2<input id="y2" type="number" step="0.01" /></label><br>
```